# Does Instance#get() return the same instance for @ApplicationScoped beans in CDI?

Tags: java, cdi

If an `@ApplicationScoped` bean is obtained through `Instance<T>#get()`, does subsequent calls to `get()` reuse the same instance (I know for sure the same `ProxyObject` is used)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If an `@ApplicationScoped` bean is obtained through `Instance<T>#get()`, does subsequent calls to `get()` reuse the same instance?

**Short answer:** Yes, a *proxy* of same instance will be returned. Keep reading for more details.

---

From the [`Instance<T>`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) documentation:

> The inherited `Provider.get()` method returns a contextual references for the unique bean that matches the required type and required qualifiers [...]

See the following quote from the [CDI specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html) which defines *contextual reference*:

> **[5.4. Client proxies](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#client_proxies)**
>
> An injected reference, or reference obtained by programmatic lookup, is usually a *contextual reference* as defined by [Contextual reference for a bean](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#contextual_reference).
>
> A contextual reference to a bean with a normal scope, as defined in [Normal scopes and pseudo-scopes](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#normal_scope), is not a direct reference to a contextual instance of the bean (the object returned by `Contextual.create()`). Instead, the contextual reference is a *client proxy* object. A client proxy implements/extends some or all of the bean types of the bean and delegates all method calls to the current instance (as defined in [Normal scopes and pseudo-scopes](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#normal_scope)) of the bean.
>
> [...]

Regarding *normal scopes*, the [CDI specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html) mentions the following:

> Contexts with normal scopes must obey the following rule:
>
> *Suppose beans A, B and Z all have normal scopes. Suppose A has an injection point x, and B has an injection point y. Suppose further that both x and y resolve to bean Z according to the rules of typesafe resolution. If a is the current instance of A, and b is the current instance of B, then both a.x and b.y refer to the same instance of Z. This instance is the current instance of Z.*

> All normal scopes must be explicitly declared `@NormalScope`, to indicate to the container that a client proxy is required.

If you inspect the [`@ApplicationScoped`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html) annotation, you'll find out it's annotated with [`@NormalScope`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/context/NormalScope.html):

```java
@Target(value = { TYPE, METHOD, FIELD })
@Retention(value = RUNTIME)
@Documented
@NormalScope
@Inherited
public @interface ApplicationScoped
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. clientproxy selects the instance from the applicationscope context.

https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html

Instance#get() returns a contextual references